# Why does python refuse to serialize this dictionary under a special case

Tags: python, django, json, serialization

I am using the following libraries: Django 1.6.1, python 3.3.2, and django-restless 0.0.7. I have a view, which serializes a user into a json object using the serialize method provided from django-restless, found here http://django-restless.readthedocs.org/en/latest/#restless.models.serialize. When implemented, it looks like

```
fields = [
    'pk',
    'username',
    'job_title',
    'company',
    'interests',
    'email',
    'website',
    'image',
    ('posts', lambda user: user.get_posts())
]
serialized_user = serialize(request.user, fields=fields)
print(type(serialized_user), serialized_user)
```

which then gives something like

```
<class 'dict'> {'posts': [], 'interests': None, 
'image': 'https://secure.gravatar.com/avatar/', 'company': None, 
'email': None, 'job_title': None, 'username': 'user-94376642', 'pk': 3, 
'website': None}
```

What is strange is when I call json.dumps on serialized_user; that is,

```
json.dumps(serailzed_user)
```

I am given the error

```
[] is not JSON serializable
```

Now, if I copy the output into a separate dictionary, it serializes normally and does not return an error. Why is this?

---

### Update

I changed the code as stated, and it gives me an AttributeError

```
AttributeError
'str' object has no attribute '_meta'
```

in the django/core/serializers/base.py file

```
concrete_model = obj._meta.concrete_model
```

I also have the following information passed over from the stacktrace,

```
obj 'interests'
self <django.core.serializers.json.Serializer object at 0x7f37037ca690>
queryset    
{'company': None,
 'email': None,
 'image': 'https://secure.gravatar.com/avatar/',
 'interests': None,
 'job_title': None,
 'pk': 3,
 'posts': [],
 'username': 'user-94376642',
 'website': None}
options{}
```

Comment: try model_to_dict custom django method from django.forms.models import model_to_dict
model_to_dict(instance, fields=[], exclude=[])

Comment: Does this support the user of lambdas, or calling functions from a model?

Comment: I do not know try it,  But why do you want to do that?

Comment: I need to call a function which returns other models serialized in a special way, which reference the user

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm assuming your `get_posts` method returns a queryset?

And also, when you do `json.dumps(serialized_user)` you are using Python's built in `json` module, i.e. `import json`?

So you have two problems:

1. A Django queryset is a lazy object... it is evaluated when you `print(serialized_user)` which is why you see the empty list there, but it's not actually an empty list when you are trying to serialize it, it's a Django `QuerySet` object
2. Python's json module can't serialize Django `QuerySet` objects

EDIT

We can't just use the custom JSON serializer provided by Django for this purpose:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/serialization/#serializing-data

...because it *only* works on Django QuerySet or model instances, but here we have a dict (containing a queryset).

Looking at [an example in the Restless docs](http://django-restless.readthedocs.org/en/latest/#restless.models.serialize) it seems like you may be best to find a way to not have a queryset in the dict you want to serialize, eg:

```
fields = [
    'pk',
    'username',
    'job_title',
    'company',
    'interests',
    'email',
    'website',
    'image',
    ('posts', lambda user: list(user.get_posts().values()))
]
```

in this case you don't need the Django serializer any more, you can go back to `json.dumps(serialized_user)`

Comment: That raises an error with the django serializer. Do you know of any examples of using the json serializer other than what the documentation provides?

Comment: hmm I see, Django serializer _only_ works on Django queryset, whereas here we have a dict containing a queryset

Comment: You are right, I did not specify nested fields. I will add corrections to my question